# How to fix UpdraftPlus's memory issue?

Tags: php, memory, php.ini

I've tried to restore a backup version of my website through Updraft Plus, a WP Plugin that allows users to backup the website every few days.

However, it cannot complete the backup due to this error:
Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 35651584) (tried to allocate 23556215 bytes)

I understand this issue may be fixed by editing the php.ini file, but I am unable to find the php.ini file through WP File Manager.

Also, editing the wp-config.php file doesn't seem to help either.

Comment: Who is your host? They may have support documentation that tells you how to do this.

Comment: My host is LunarPages: https://lunarpages.com/